# add-apt-repository very slow

Tags: 19.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 on a Razer Blade 15 (2019) and am trying to install OpenRazer drivers so I can control the keyboard backlighting.

I go into terminal and run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrazer/stable`. When I hit enter, it sits there for 5-10 minutes and finally asks whether or not I want to add the repository.

I hit enter to confirm, wait another minute or so, and it says that it timed out trying to retrieve the gpg key.

I've tried:

1. Restarting and running the command again
2. Disabling IPv6
3. Letting Software & Updates choose the best download mirror
4. Using multiple different keyservers
5. Removing all repositories with missing keys

Nothing seems to work. I get the same behaviour every time. Is there any way to fix this?